# Selecting n random elements from an array/list in Python

Tags: python

I came across a piece of code to select n random elements from an array/list using another randomized array and I can't figure out how it happened. The code goes something like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
data = np.linspace(-10.0, 10.0, 100)
rnd = np.random.permutation(len(data))
n=20
slic = data[rnd[:n]]
print(slic)
```

I understand normal slicing but I don't understand how the array `data` is sliced using  random elements from another array `rnd`.

Comment: It's not an array/list, it's specifically a numpy array: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing

Comment: Ok i got it. The randomized array rnd is providing the indices of the for the array data. I understand now. The article was helpful. Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe